# Падает на сервере бот написанный на python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, сервер, vds, discord.py

У меня есть купленный vds сервер, на нём у меня стоят два Discord бота. Может пройти от 1 до 5 дней, и один из них обязательно перестанет работать. Даже обычный "hello world" через какое то время упадёт.

Я бы хотел узнать у меня у одно так, и что можно с этим сделать ?

Бот на python3.7 - 3.6

Запускаю через команду:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python3 script.py &
```

дистрибутив Ubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 1):

У падений скриптов могут быть совершенно разные причины. Решения тоже разные. Вы, судя по всему, запускаете скрипт через SSH-сессию, в таком случае процесс с ботом будет убит по закрытию этой сессии (однако странно, что 1-5 дней).

**Простое решение:** Запускайте код с помощью команды `nohup`, которая позволяет держать процессы живыми после закрытия SSH:

```bsh
nohup python path/to/your/file.py
```

Но если случится ошибка в коде, то процесс погибнет и всё.

**Хорошее решение:** Запускайте код с помощью [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/installing.html) или [systemd](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/systemd) – в таком случае после гибели код будет перезапущен. Это удобно для процессов вроде бекенда сайтов, которые должны работать постоянно и перезапускаться, если падают. Для этого нужно настроить выбранную программу, написать конфиг для демонизации вашего процесса, см. документацию и примеры там.

---

Но помимо этих решений важно также предотвращать краши и вообще ошибки. На Питоне можно легко оборачивать всё приложение в блоки `try-except` или воткнуть его в главный event loop, и там логировать происходящие ошибки. Это позволит программе не падать полностью, а коду впоследствии улучшаться на основе точной информации о происхождении проблем.

Также полезно сделать юнит-тесты (для этого в Питоне тоже есть встроенный функционал), что позволит быстро находить банальные и не очень ошибки – это особенно важно в крупных и серьёзных проектах.